# Text retrieved on multiple rows on Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a kind of new to Excel VBA. Here's the problem:
Given a identifier, I want to retireve some text from a web page. Ideally I want to store the text of the page in a single cell. I created a function that creates a QueryTable but, sometimes, the retrieved text is copied on multiple rows.

Is there a way to place all the text on a single cell?

Here's the code of my function:

```
Function Articolo(myRange As Range, code As String)
  Dim myURL As String
  Dim myName As String

  myURL = "URL;http://techstore.runner.it/feed/dettagli_csv.php?codcli=111367&pwd=03142110786&sku=" & code
  myName = "dettagli_csv.php?codcli=111367&pwd=03142110786&sku=" & code

  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    myURL _
    , Destination:=myRange)
    .Name = myName
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = False
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = True
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
End Function
```

As test you can use 8E4374 as code

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Excel is notorious for trying to "help" by formatting things the way it thinks you want.  Characters such as `tabs` and new lines are generally going to act as delimiters and cause your value to span multiple rows/columns.  The best workaround is to check the returned string, strip out those values, and then enter it into the cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querytables are often slow and cumbersome. If you use one of the httprequest objects instead it's much quicker and you have more control over how to parse the response. Below is basic example that doesn't manage sessions or check if the page is cached.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim code As String

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    code = "8E4374"
    Articolo rng, code

End Sub

Sub Articolo(myRange As Range, code As String)
  Dim myURL As String
  Dim myName As String

  myURL = "http://techstore.runner.it/feed/dettagli_csv.php?codcli=111367&pwd=03142110786&sku=" & code
  myRange.Value = ExecuteWebRequest(myURL)

End Sub

Function ExecuteWebRequest(ByVal url As String) As String

    Dim oXHTTP As Object

    Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oXHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    oXHTTP.send
    ExecuteWebRequest = oXHTTP.responseText
    Set oXHTTP = Nothing

End Function
```

**EDIT:**  the above code is designed to run as a Sub rather than a UDF. Since a UDF cannot affect other cells the only option is to return the string to the calling cell or call set up the code to run as either an event or from a control (eg a button)

Below is an example UDF, it's called from Excel using `=Articolo(C1)` where C1 is any cell containing the required code eg 8E4374

```
Option Explicit

Function Articolo(ByVal code As String) As String
Dim myURL As String

  myURL = "http://techstore.runner.it/feed/dettagli_csv.php?codcli=111367&pwd=03142110786&sku=" & code
  Articolo = ExecuteWebRequest(myURL)

End Function

Function ExecuteWebRequest(ByVal url As String) As String
Dim oXHTTP As Object

    Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    oXHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    oXHTTP.send
    ExecuteWebRequest = oXHTTP.responseText
    Set oXHTTP = Nothing

End Function
```

Also, as this is making http requests, everytime you force a full re-calc your UDF's will also re-calc which is probably not what you want as you could be making hundreds or thousands of requests. I would suggest running it once only from a defined loop such as

```
For Each code in Listofcodes : <Download Page> : Next code
```

Comment: If I call, for instance, =Articolo(A1;C1) for some reason it returns #VALUE! but if I ask to evaluate the formula (by pressing on the ! sign when selected) the result is correct. Do you know what's wrong with that? Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: `=Articolo(A1;C1)` is using the function Articolo as a `UDF`. It's not possible to change other cells with a UDF so you would need to return the function to the calling cell using `=Articolo(C1)` and change the function. I'll update my answer to show how to make it work as a UDF.

Comment: Hi ooo don't worry! I managed to fix it thank to your suggestion on UDF functions! Now the function gets only one parameter (cose As String) and returns the value in Articolo = ExecuteWebRequest(myURL). Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data coming from that URL has carriage return and line feeds embedded in it.  That's why it's separating into different cells in excel.

One solution would be to run VBA code to do the query, strip out the carriage return/line feed characters and then put the results into a cell.  The problem would be that you'd have to run the code to update, rather than excel taking care of the refreshes.

A simpler answer might be to add another cell with a formula like this:

```
=A1&" "&A2&" "&A3&" "&A4
```